# Evince complains about missing --filesystem=xdg-run/gvfsd privileges, how can I add those privileges

Tags: permissions, evince, flatpak

On 22.04, when using evince on the command line to add text annotations to a PDF and then save it, evince complains

```
The peer-to-peer connection failed: Error while getting peer-to-peer dbus connection: Could not connect: Permission denied. Falling back to the session bus.
Your application is probably missing --filesystem=xdg-run/gvfsd privileges.
```

**Question:** Since I regularly use evince from the command line it would be great to either tell it not to bother to log this or give it the necessary privileges. I found [documentation](https://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/sandbox-permissions.html#filesystem-access) describing that the privileges are provided at build time, but I wonder how they can be changed after the installation.

I could create a shell function around `evince` to filter out and ignore this specific message, but that looks like a bad hack.

Comment: [Here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1951075) is a discussion of this error. Does Nautilus open when this happens? Do you have Keybase installed?

Comment: @jos Indeed the error appears in the moment a file manager opens to allow me to select the file to save in. No sure if it is `nautilus`, at least `ps` does not show it.

Comment: One solution is probably to use qpdfview instead :-)

Comment: @Jos ... and not, keybase is not installed.